# What is the most preferred way to pass object attributes to a function in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I am certain I am doing this "incorrectly" even though it works.  Right now when I call a function I just pass the whole object i.e.

```
class my_file_obj:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.owner = None
        self.file_type = None
        self.fileflag = 0
        self.md5 = None
```

The function call, where `file_obj1` is an instance of `my_file_obj`:

```
some_function(file_obj1)
```

and then referencing the attributes I need as needed within the function.

What is the "python"/correct way of doing this?

- `some_function(file_obj1)`
- `some_function(file_obj1.filename)`
- `the_filename = file_obj1.filename

  some_function(the_filename)`

Comment: It's really your call. Do you only need to use the file name? Do you have cases where you'd pass in a file name that does not have an object associated with it?

Comment: @RafeKettler: I think that suffices as an answer.

Comment: Not sure if directly accessing the data members of an object is recommended in Python. You may use access functions for this, like `def getFilename(self)` or something similar (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method for more information).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's quite obvious. It depends on whether `some_function` needs the whole object or just the filename, in which case you pass the whole `my_file_obj` instance or just the filename.

Comment: thanks for the responses.  i wasnt sure if python had interfaces or if a getter type function was the preferred method.  i am assuming that passing the whole object would be more memory/computationally expensive, correct?

Comment: @user982599: All names in Python are references. The only difference is in attribute lookup time (`foo` vs `foo.bar`), but that's likely to be negligible.

Comment: I don't have benchmarks, but under the hood what you are actually doing is passing a reference to the instance of object to the function, not the object itself. So it should not be any more computationally intensive to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think `some_function(file_obj1)` is the most pythonic.

`some_function(file_obj1.filename)` doesn't pass the object to the function, it only passes the filename attribute as a string. It then would require a lot of fiddly code to get the rest of the object's attributes.

Answer (score 1):

All the ways are acceptable and which you will choose will depend on your application (or design) choices.

```
# with this call the file_obj1 object reference is sent to some_function()
some_function(file_obj1)

# with this call there is no pass by reference. If filename is a 
# string it is copied to some_function
some_function(file_obj1.filename)

# same as before, but here you are allocating a new var and copying the content
# to some_function
the_filename = file_obj1.filename
some_function(the_filename)
```

Comment: Technically speaking, this is misleading - Python is really [call-by-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference/986495#986495). In your second example you're still passing the actual string object, but it just happens to be immutable, unlike the `file_obj1` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Or you may add a `def __str__(self): return self.filename` method to your class (because, maybe, printing a file object should return its name in your design anyways) and accept any kind of object for your function. The function then, for example, looks like this:

```
def openFile(obj):
    return open(str(obj), 'rU')
```

Like this, the function accepts both strings and objects of your class. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing.

Not sure if this design is recommended -- just want to point out something less obvious. Maybe this is even pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you want to do and what your goal is.

If you have a function that looks something like this:

```
def some_function(file_thingy):
   with open(file_thingy.filename, 'w') as f:
       f.write("Icky Icky Icky Patang NeeeeWom!")
```

Then it makes things much more generic - as long as you pass an object in that has a `.filename` attribute that is a string then your function will work. A more common example of this is when people talk about duck typing. If it looks like a duck, walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, well then it's a duck!

So if you have the following function:

```
def do_duck_things(a_duck):
    print(a_duck.appearance)
    a_duck.waddle()
    a_duck.quack()
    print("It must be a duck!")
```

Then you could pass it an instance of:

```
class Duck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.appearance = "White, like the AFLAC duck"

    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaaaaack!")

    def waddle(self):
        print("The duck waddles.")
```

or an instance of either of these classes:

```
class UglyDuckling:
    def __init__(self):
        self.appearance = "Suspiciously like a baby goose"

    def waddle(self):
        print("The ugly duckling waddles a bit like a duck.")

    def quack(self):
        print("Hoooonk!")

class Human:
    def __init__(self):
        self.appearance = "Looks like a human in a duck costume"

    def waddle(self):
        print("Surprisingly, he waddles quite like a duck.")

    def quack(self):
        print("<A sound quite like Donald Duck would make>")
```

So in your case, it really depends on what your function should be doing. If all it's doing is reading the contents of a file, then you can (and probably should) just send it a filename. But if you want to do something like, say, check the file against your stored MD5, or set that MD5, then it's perfectly appropriate to pass in the object.

HTH